# Why is my Google Analytics data removed?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I'm sure I had several visitors from Germany but now I don't see any visits from Germany in my analytics report. What could be the reason?

I'm looking at Audience -> Overview section. Does it reset every month? My other site does not get reset.

I'm sure I have not messed with anything other than just looking at the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the report date range. Google Analytics doesn't reset, but everyday you go into a report, the date range will automatically be set to the last month starting the day before today.

For example, if you logged into your account on September 03, the date range would have been Aug 03 - Sept 02. Then you login again today, September 11, the date range is Aug 11 - Sept 10.